# C#: Capturing still images, from multiple (USB )cameras

Tags: c#, webcam

I need some guidance.
I have to create a simple program, that captures still images every n Seconds, from 4 cameras, attached with USB.
My problem is, that the cameras cannot be "open" at the same time, as it will exceed the USB Bus bandwidth, so I will have to cycle between them.

How to do this, i'm not so sure about.
I've tried using EmguCV, which is a .NET wrapper for OpenCV, but I'm having trouble controlling the quality of my images. I can capture 1280x720, as intended, but it seems like they are just scaled up, and all the image files are around 200kb.

Any ideas on how to do this, properly?

Comment: Can you buy single image cameras rather than video cameras?

Comment: @kenny Unfortunately we'll have to use the cameras we already have, which are MS Lifecam studio's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but this is how I have ended up doing it.
I continued with EmguCV. The images are not very large (file size), but it seems like that is not an issue. They are saving with 96 dpi, and it looks pretty good.

I cycle through the attached cameras, by initiating the camera, taking a snapshot and then releasing the camera again.

It's not as fast as I had hoped, but it works. In average, there is 2 seconds between each image.